# Change image on click then back to original image on another image click/html jscript

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, jquery-events, jscript

First of all, I have basically no knowledge on how to write JavaScript, so my problem might be quite simple to answer, but I've done some research and I didn't find anything yet.
I'd like to know **how to change my image on click then back to original image when another image is clicked, not the same one.**

In my research, I've found how to go from one image to another on click and I found this :

```
function changeImage(img){
  if(img.src=="resources/items/original_image.png"){
    img.src="resources/items/icon2blue.png";
  }else {
    img.src="resources/items/original_image.png"; 
  }
}
```

which works perfectly, but is not really want I want to do. And I don't know how to modify this to arrive where I want to go haha.

I found another post on the forum with the same problem but couldn't make any of the solution answered work.
thanks to anybody who helps :)

Answer (score 0):

From how I understand the question, there are two images, and when the main/original image is clicked, that same one should be changed to another image, but when another image is clicked, then the original image should be changed from the `icon2blue.png` to the original image it was.

Okay assuming your first image is

```
<img class="first-image" src="resources/items/original_image.png" alt="first image" />
```

and the second one is

```
<img class="second-image" src="source/not/specified.png" alt="first image" />
<!-- Set the source to whatever that image is -->
```

Your JavaScript file will be as so:

```
const image1 = document.querySelector("img.first-image") // This gets the original image using it's class name
const image2 = document.querySelector("img.second-image") // Gets the second image

//then make functions for setting/reverting the image source
function revertImage(){
    image1.src = "resources/items/original_image.png" // this will set the first-image back to the original
}

function changeImage(){
    image1.src = "resources/items/icon2blue.png" // this will change the first-image to the "icon2blue.png"
}

// next, listen to when the first is clicked
image1.addEventListener("click", changeImage) // so whenever the first image is clicked, the image's source would be changed to the "icon2blue"

// when the second image is clicked
image2.addEventListener("click", revertImage) // anytime the second image is clicked, the first image's source would be changed back to the original source
```

Hope I answered your question. If I misunderstood something, let me know :)